# Creating CSV file with Header and Sending it through the Flat File Assembler

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have to query a view in database, map this schema and create a CSV file with Header. The Header should be the name of each field in the view. I tried using the Flat file Schema to create a Header Record and Body Record.I created the Header Record with Elements having the default value as the name of each field in the view. It works good.But I am wondering if there is any other better way of doing this. It would be great if anyone suggest me the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is likely the most common solution for this requirement.  There's nothing wrong with it.

There may be different solutions, but not necessarily better.

Comment: I am wondering if the database field name changes in the future. Then, we will have to update the header manually.

Comment: Consider, that's a big 'if'.  Database fields don't change on the fly and if they did, you'd have to update every reference as well anyway so it's not something I would ever worry about.

Comment: If so I will follow the approach I used. Thanks  so much.